# get the clicked item from a IsItemClickEnabled ListView in C# and WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

how can I get the clicket elevent from a `ListView` which has the `IsItemClickEnabled` enabled?
I know how to get the selected Item/Index but not the clicked item.

`ItemClick` is working but I can not say s.th. like:

```
Object selection = listView1.SelectedItem;
```

**EDIT**:
I have a ListView and I need to catch the clicked item from this list in the following method:

```
private void listView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
...            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something, but doesn't the following work for you?

```
private void lv_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as String;
}
```

Here I assume the items in the list are simple strings, but in general they'll be whatever type you are using in the collection you've bound to the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property of the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can also try the `SelectionChanged` event, and get the clicked item as `e.AddedItems` or `MyListView.SelectedItem` or `MyListView.SelectedItems`.

Comment: no, the selectionChange event is for a other thing in my app. I just can use the ItemClicked